# Insert dbnull in SQL database doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql

I need to insert a null value in the database a tried many approaches but doesn't result

I tried:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(ValuesFields.Capacitance.ToString()) ? "," + null : "," + ValuesFields.Capacitance.ToString().Replace(",", ".")
```

---

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(ValuesFields.Capacitance.ToString()) ? "," + DDNull.Value : "," + ValuesFields.Capacitance.ToString().Replace(",", ".")
```

---

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(ValuesFields.Capacitance.ToString()) ? "," + (Object)DDNull.Value : "," + ValuesFields.Capacitance.ToString().Replace(",", ".")
```

Comment: What is the result?  You get any error?  Is that column allow null?...

Comment: Please post the error you are getting

Comment: Are you using a Parameter to pass this value? Please expand to a full [mcve] and include the error message. "... [doesn't work](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)" isn't helpful.

Comment: Instead of `"," + null : ","`, you'd have to have `null` in the string query, `",null,"`. However, never, ever create your parameters by just concatenating values.

Comment: The result is  empty like this ',62.2,,,,,5.993084247,  i'm not using parameters

Comment: `DBNull.Value.ToString()`, which is used implicitly when concatenating strings, is the empty string. If you don't want that, insert something else. As per the others, if your intent is to insert actual `NULL` values in columns, use properly typed parameters, not strings. Doubly so when you're inserting things like `float`s, `double`s, or `decimal`s, and doing so by replacing separators. This is ugly, brittle and possibly subject to SQL injection when string columns get involved.

Comment: Do not use query concatenation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are doing query concatenation instead of properly using parameters. If you had used parameters this problem wouldn't have arisen in the first place.

Since you have not tagged a particular DB, I cannot provide concrete solution. But look into how to use parameterized queries in whatever DB you are using.

- SQL server uses @parameter to specify a parameter.
- MySQL also uses @parameter syntax.

You can then add individual parameters to your command object by calling

`command.AddParameterWithValue(parameterName, parameterValue);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing something like this:

```
"," + null + ","
```

do this:

```
+ ", null ," +
```

If you know there is a column in the database that accepts null values, and you want to insert null into that column, just hard code it into the SQL string. Don't bother trying to manipulate an object in HLL to get it to produce the string "null".

NOTE: Using a string like this to insert into a database is not a best practice. Here is some example reading to get started: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlphp/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries/